# Closed form solution for Mean-Variance optimization under constraint

Tags: portfolio-optimization, mean-variance

Is there a closed form solution for the vector weight $w$ for the following mean-variance optimization problem?

$\max_w w'\mu - \frac{\gamma}{2}w'\Sigma w $

s.t.

$w'z\geq \bar{z}$

where $w, z$  are N x 1 vectors, $\bar{z}$ is a constant, $\Sigma$ is a variance-covariance matrix, that is symmetric and positive definite. Note I assumed the existence of risk-free asset with $r_f=0$, that's why I don't have the usual $w'\boldsymbol{1}=1$ constraint.

If I write the following Lagrangian:

$L(w,\lambda) = w'\mu - \frac{\gamma}{2}w'\Sigma w  +\lambda (w'z -\bar{z}) $

Is there a way to have a closed-form solution for $w$ (i.e. as a function of only $\bar{z},\mu,\Sigma$)?

Comment: In general, no. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming

Comment: Thanks! So even if $\Sigma$ is positive definite and symmetric, there is no way to have maybe a closed form. Maybe by splitting the problem whether the constraint is binding or not

Comment: If all restrictions are binding (with equality), the problem is greatly reduced and indeed solved in closed form. But that’s not the common case, IMO